# Loading missing lookup records in the drop down

Tags: sql, .net, metadata, lookup

I have employee data capture application. .net and t-sql.

It has number of lookup(metadata) tables which used to populate drop downs in the UI. ex: "Departments". Every lookup table has active flag. Sometimes this flag set to false. This means I should not load those inactive “Departments” in the drop down. This perfectly works for ADD NEW EMPLOYEE scenario. But in EDIT EMPLOYEE scenario, if one lookup record (Department-HR) happens to be inactive but associated with the EMPLOYEE for some reson, I have a problem that the Department-HR is missing in the drop down to select.

I know question looks silly. I can pass EmployeeId and load Active + all associated departments to EmployeeId, but I want to know a smarter and cleaner way to handle the situation.

Answer (score 0):

Well one approach would be to prevent the deletion of a department if it's in use by an employee in the first place. It would be more helpful to the user if they were notified of the problem at the point that they could cause the employee data to be invalid.

If you had an `Employees` and `Departments` table in your database (with a one-to-many, or many-to-many relationship), then you would have appropriate foreign keys configured. If you were actually deleting department rows from the `Departments` table (as opposed to marking them as inactive), then obviously you would get a foreign key violation if there were any employee records referencing the department that was being deleted.

If you are marking departments as 'inactive', then your UI should probably surface the list of employees that are referencing that department when the user attempts to mark it as inactive. They could then be provided with a UI for assigning the employees to an alternative department.

Either way, I'm not sure why you have tables specifically for populating the department dropdown list? Why isn't this populated from the `Departments` table directly? The add new employee screen and edit employee screen can query to get a list of all active departments, and the edit screen could also check the active state of the current department for the employee, and then prompt the user to reassign the employee when they enter the edit screen.

Comment: The department drop down is populated from Department table directly. "The add new employee screen and edit employee screen can query to get a list of all active departments, and the edit screen could also check the active state of the current department for the employee, and then prompt the user to reassign the employee when they enter the edit screen." is the solution i guess. Thank you for the quick answer!

Comment: Ok, it was the 'metadata lookup tables' that you mentioned that suggested you weren't querying the source tables directly.